# Finding consecutive numeric oder alphanumeric substrings in a string

Tags: objective-c, string

I want to find consecutive numeric oder alphanumeric substrings in ascending oder descending order in a string, like "2345", "8765", "defg" oder "srqp". Are there code snippets (preferred Objective-C) to do this? Thx!

Comment: Is that an exercise? It seems to to me, and you didn't provide any tries. Wild guess, you could use the unichar value to check if the next value difference is -1 or +1. "DeFg" (uppercase vs lowercase) works?

Comment: You need to show examples of what you mean? What does work what doesn't work? Does "1" work? Does "1", "234" work? what does that return etc... Which bit are you stuck on?